# How fatal is appendicitis?

Tags: appendicitis

I am wondering how fatal is appendicitis if a surgery (or any other professional help) is not performed. There seem to be no statistics readily available. Common language sounds like "if left untreated, appendix can rupture, which will cause peritonitis and can be fatal", but I am wondering about the likelihood of this scenario - at this point I have no idea whether its more like 100% or 1%

Comment: What has your research revealed?

Comment: This is a more interesting question than one might think. But, you might clarify what you mean by "other professional help". It would be unethical to collect data on what proportion of patients die with no treatment at all. If you're asking what happens to an uncomplicated case of acute appendicitis when it's managed medically instead of surgically, we have data on that.

Comment: @Carey Gregory unfortunately, not much. I could find some data on historic incidence, but not pre-XX-century mortality, and statistics on mortality in undeveloped countries. Unfortunately the latter does not seem to be differentiated between treated and untreated cases.

Comment: @De Novo by "other professional help" I mean primarily antibiotics. Statistics on what % of cases are "complicated" can definitely help me, though I understand I can't just use this number as a proxy for potential mortality.

Comment: @CareyGregory - The *"if left untreated..."* quote can be found in different forms everywhere you look online so it does show prior research in my mind.  As it stands, and as indicated by De Novo, this is an interesting question which could be framed in the sense of **is it the appendicitis that kills or is it the peritonitis caused by rupture? PLUS how likely is it that the appendix may rupture**

Comment: The % of cases that are complicated will not be as helpful as you'd like, because this data is going to be "at the time of presentation", and not provide useful information about what would happen if nobody did anything. I'm afraid a modern answer to the question "what happens if you don't do anything" is not possible, since [you can't ethically do a natural history study on a disease that can be safely and effectively treated](https://www.cdc.gov/tuskegee/timeline.htm).

Comment: @De Novo I was not thinking about a deliberate study, but rather if someone was collecting statistics on cases of appendicitis that were for some reasons left untreated.